# Aleks buttons that aren't needed?

Tags: math-software

I'm solving a problem on it, and to the side it gives me the button for fraction formatting. The buttons it gives are different for each problem. Does the fact the it's there mean that the answer has some sort of fraction in it? Or would it give me that even if it's not going to be needed in the answer. At first it seemed like the things in the button where all things you needed for the given problem, but now I'm on a question, and I'm very sure there is no fraction in the answer but... it's throwing me off and making me second guess myself. Is that all it's doing? Being there throwing me off? Or should I rethink my answer based on it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the specific behaviour of a proprietary piece of software.

Comment: Yea.. Sorry. I wasn't really sure of any place to ask this. I just hoped maybe someone around here would be familiar with it and know. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I teach classes using ALEKS.  It will sometimes include formatting tabs that are not needed in the answer, not to throw you off, but for those students who mistakenly think that they need it.  Imagine how frustrating it would be if you thought you had the right answer but were unable to enter it.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting paranoid that I was forgetting something doing problems I'm normally perfectly comfortable with.